# Meaning of "mash" in "to do the mash"

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary

I could not find a proper definition for *mash* from the song "Monster mash". I assume it does not refer to mashed potatos. Maybe it's some kind of a dance. The lyrics is

> For my monster from his slab began to rise
>
> And suddenly to my surprise
>
> He *did the mash*
>
> He *did the monster mash*

Comment: Perhaps because *it was a graveyard smash!* From the song: *He did the mash. He did the monster mash. The monster mash. It was a graveyard smash.* This must be a "smash hit" around the graveyard, I guess. :)

Comment: [***mosh***](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=mosh) *- "to dance (with a certain amount of violence) to metal music in a tightly packed arena," 1987, perhaps a variant of **mash**. Related: **Mosh pit**.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Monster Mash* is, indeed, a form of dance which is being referred to.  Presumably is it similar to the *Mashed Potato*, which I believe was a popular (or at least better-known) dance at the time the song was written.  Compare the lyrics from "Do You Love Me (Now That I Can Cance)"; e. g. "I can do the Twist".

Comment: I suppose there *might* have been an actual dance routine called "The Mashed Potato", but I think most people probably only know of it through the lyrics of [Chris Motez's 1962 song "Let's Dance"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let's_Dance_(Chris_Montez_song)) [*Well let's dance, well let's dance
We'll do the twist, the stomp, **the mashed potato too**,
Any old dance that you wanna do
But let's dance, well let's dance*](http://songmeanings.com/songs/view/3530822107858579875/)

Comment: The *Mashed Potato* is also specifically referenced in "Do You Love Me (Now That I Can Dance)"; it was pretty definitely a Thing back in the 1950s or 1960s.

Comment: Indeed. Interestingly, both these songs were released in 1962, but I only remember "Let's Dance" from my UK-based youth (perhaps "Do You Love Me" was more popular in the US). I'd also note that the Wikipedia page for the latter says [*The **main point of the song** is to name the Mashed Potato, The Twist, and many other fad dances of the 1960s.*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do_You_Love_Me)

Comment: [The Mashed Potato](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mashed_Potato_%28dance%29), and instructional [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nzGPpPUML94)

Comment: @Sean - Thanks! I've always wondered if it was even a real dance; I've only heard it referenced in the lyrics of songs like [_Land of 1000 Dances_](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/wilsonpickett/landof1000dances.html), and I've wondered if there ever was such a thing, or if it was just some kind urban lyric. Maybe tonight I'll put on some Christmas music, and bust a mashed potato! (A Yuletide Mash, of course, not a Monster Mash.)

Comment: The *mash potato* was popular immediately after the twist in the US. It's an awkward dance, and wasn't long-lived.